Does godot optimize(remove) casts during build?
So I've been playing around with godot with GDSCRIPT. And since it's not strongly typed it does not provide inteli sense for most of things that come from outside the script itself like referencing nodes unless you cast them.
I've tried casting a variable in a loop over milion of iterations.
$AnimatedSprite2D.sprite_frames.get_animation_names()
and then
($AnimatedSprite2D as AnimatedSprite2D).sprite_frames.get_animation_names()
which was just a little slower. I know that it isn't really an issue since the difference in 1 milion iterations was like 30 ms but I'm curious if that stuff(casting) gets optimized (removed) during production build.

No, casting is a defined operation in the GDScript VM. Don't worry about it. Work on your game.
